# Automate Power Bi report creation>

Tags: automation, powerbi, ui-automation

I have a requirement to test upload of **power bi [pbix, rdl]** files in my application.
I have to create power bi reports that has a connection to a sql server data source. The table scheme would remain constant. But, the connection string will always vary. How can I automate the report creation?
I have tried to parameterize the connection details and have saved the report in **.pbit** format for the ease of report creation. But, I need to create these reports run-time. I have been using Power Bi desktop for creating the reports.
I am also Selenium as the tool for interacting the browser.

Comment: Publish the report and use [Update Datasources In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources-in-group) or [Update Parameters In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters-in-group) API to change the data source

Comment: Also you can dynamically create reports in the browser with the Javascript API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-authoring-overview